# DOM Pdf stream doesn't work with Android browser (it does on Windows)

Tags: php, android, dompdf, android-download-manager

Even though on Microsoft Edge/Google Chrome on Windows 10 everything works just fine, I am getting lots of issues while streaming the pdf into Chrome for Android.
The download doesn't finish, looks like stuck and it doesn't complete at all after couple of minutes. I've tried on my phone and in another one getting the same result.

I am using DOMPdf as suggested in the tutorial in the first page of the website:

```
// Instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf( array('enable_remote' => true) );

// Load HTML content
$dompdf->loadHtml( $HTML );

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$filename   =   "File_Export_" . date( 'd_m_Y' ) . ".PDF";
//header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $dompdf->output() ) );  
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");
$dompdf->stream( $filename , array('Attachment' => true ) );
exit(0);
```

I've tried adding many differen headers (content-type, content-length - as it is commented in the script) without any help.
I just referrer to the page as normal URL in Android, as following:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("my url"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Any idea?
Thank you.

PS: I've already read and applied [this](http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/) without any success

Comment: Not a lot to go on. Might try an [`ob_clean`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) just before the render of the PDF. Make sure your not sending some other crud out prior, different browsers handle that differently.

Comment: Never used a "stream" with this... I've always used `header("Content-type:application/pdf");`. Any reason to not use `$dompdf->output();`?

Comment: @ficuscr Please write your comment in an answer so I can mark it as correct answer!! I was attempting to solve the whole day and you just solved my problem!

Comment: sure thing. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you had output emitted prior to buffering to the stream. This could be white space, a warning/notice, many things potentially.

A sort of cure-all for that is to use [**`ob_clean`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php).

> This function discards the contents of the output buffer.

This issue is common with session errors also, where output has been sent prior to the headers. Making sure your PHP error logging and levels are set appropriately can sometimes help detect this also.